# Capability error while binding delphi grid wirth stored procedure

Tags: delphi, informix, dbgrid

I am getting capability error whenever I am trying to set active property tue. I want to bind the grid with the stored procedure that takes one parameter.

If I do it through TQuery How do I specify the fields. I am using wwDBGrid.

```
MessageMembershipSelectQuery.Params[0].AsString :=  
custQuery.FieldByName('cust_code').AsString;
MessageMembershipSelectQuery.Active := True;
```

Please guide

Comment: Maybe you could show us the query sentence? It would be helpful. Also, what dataset exactly are you using and what delphi version?

Comment: I am ausing Delphi 2010, and also its infopower WWDBGrid. 
When I set active := true it goves me capability not supported.

Comment: Query Sentence is 
Execute Procedure(:custcode);
I have specified the parameter also.

Comment: As I am trying to add fields I get this error capability not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace you Query component by a StoredProc component. Also, check your parameter data type. If it is indeed a string parameter, then it´s Ok to use `AsString`, but if the parameter has a different data type, like `Integer`, for instance, then you should assign it´s value by using, for instance, `AsInteger`.